# What do two consecutive minus signs mean in a return statement?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript, I have the following:

```
self.newId = 0;

self.GetNewId = () => {
                return --self.newId;
                };
```

My guess is that `return --self.newId;` does two things:

1. it returns the current value of `self.newId`
2. it then decreases the value of `self.newId` by 1. (To -1)

I assume that the next time that `GetNewId` is called, it will return `-1` and then decrease the value to `-2`, etc.

Can anyone confirm

Answer (score 14):

No. What you are describing is the *post-decrement* operator, which is written like this:

```
foo--
```

It will indeed, *first* evaluate the expression and *then* decrement the value.

This is the *pre-decrement* operator, which is written like this:

```
--foo
```

It will *first* decrement, *then* evaluate.

So, what this snippet will do is

1. it decreases the value of `self.newId` by `1`. (To `-1`)
2. it then returns the current value of `self.newId`

As a mnemonic, you can just think about reading the expression left-to-right: does the operator come first or last?

Comment: This is why I never put a decrement operator on the same line as a return statement or assignment operator.

Comment: This is why I never use languages that have such inherently imperative side-effecting constructs in the first place ;-)

Comment: Well, there are ways to use such languages safely.

Answer (score 7):

Your answer / thinking about the code is close, but not quite right.  See this [mozilla documentation on arithmetic operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) for additional details.

the line

```
return --self.newID
```

is using a prefix decrement operator.

So it subtracts *before* returning the value, not after the return.

The first call to `GetNewId()` will return -1 not 0.  It will decrement from there on.